# Rails list model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, model, attributes, controller

I have an events model that has an attribute called location that is user defined. I want to create a list of those locations sorted by their counts. How do I grab all the values of an attribute?

****EDIT****

**Events Controller**

```
def index
    @tags = Event.tag_counts.order('count DESC').limit(12)
    //code
end
```

**How I listed my other attribute tags w/ acts_as_taggable**

```
<div class="sbody sbody-2">
    <ul>
        <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
            <li>
                <%= link_to(:controller => "events", :action => "index", :search => tag.name) do %>
                    <i class="icon-tag icon-white"></i> <%= tag.name.titleize %>
                <% end %>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Event Model**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :member

    attr_accessible :blurb, :details, :category, :tags, :video, :website, :name, :avatar, :banner, :tag_list, :location, :address,
              :city, :zipcode, :state, :country, :start_date, :end_date, :start_time, :end_time

    validates :location, presence: true,
          length: {
                      maximum: 40, 
                      message: 'must not be more than 40 characters.',
                      minimum: 2,
                      message: 'must be longer than 2 characters.'
                    }
end
```

**Schema**

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.references :member
      t.text :category
      t.text :tags
      t.text :website
      t.text :video
      t.text :details
      t.text :blurb
      t.text :name

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :events, :member_id
    add_attachment :events, :banner
    add_attachment :events, :avatar
  end
end
```

Comment: So you want to loop through each event and add its location attribute to a list? What is this "count" you want to sort by? Is this how many times a location is used for different events?

Comment: We need some more information to help you out. Add your `Event` model and your schema for your `events` table.

Comment: @dkurbz Exactly. On my event events index view I want to put a scetion called 'popular locations' and yes count is how many times a location has been used. I've done this with tags and acts_as_taggable, as you can see in my edit I just don't know how to do it on my own.

Comment: @JKen13579 I added the model and schema just didn't think that it'd add much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
locations_count = Hash.new{0}  // Create Hash to store location counts (initialize counts to 0)
Event.all.each { |event| locations_count[event.location] += 1 }  // Iterate through each Event and increment the count for its location
locations_count.sort_by { |key, value| value }  // Sort location counts by the value
```

Comment: Sorry but how would I implement this? Do i need to define this as a method in my model?

Comment: This should probably go in a method in the controller for the page you want to show popular locations. Then if you change it to `@locations_count = Hash.new{0}` you can access `@locations_count` in the view. I would start with just typing it in `rails console` to verify it's working.